# Uncaught TypeError: b.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

While implementing AutoComplete places using google maps api, when i try to enter any places a bunch of errors are generated at the chrome console window. One of them is Uncaught **TypeError: b.get is not a function at Ew._.k.get (js?key=[KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initMap:106)**.

Code:

```
<!-- Google Maps API integration-->
<div class="gmaps">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
      <!-- getting the user location -->
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
      } else {
          alert('geolocation not supported');
      }
      <!-- if successfully found the location -->
      function success(position) {

          var uluru = {lat:position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 15,
              center: uluru
            });

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: uluru,
              map: map
           });
      }      
      var acOptions = {
            types: ['establishment']
        };
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'),acOptions);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds',map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            infoWindow.close();
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);
            }
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            infoWindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>');
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(e){

                infoWindow.open(map, marker);

            });
        });
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to implement the external api before you start your own script ...

Comment: What u mean by external api? Can u elaborate please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

When that code first runs, the `map` hasn't finished initializing and its bounds aren't valid.  Put that code inside a `bounds_changed` event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'bounds_changed', function() {
  autocomplete.bindTo(map, 'bounds');
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9aorz2je/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var infoWindow;
var map;

function initMap() {
  <!-- getting the user location -->
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, errorFunc);
  } else {
    alert('geolocation not supported');
  }

  function errorFunc(posErr) {
    console.log("Position Error code:" + posErr.code + " msg:" + posErr.message);
  }
  <!-- if successfully found the location -->
  function success(position) {
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var uluru = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: uluru
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
  var acOptions = {
    types: ['establishment']
  };
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), acOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    autocomplete.bindTo(map, 'bounds');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    infoWindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    infoWindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>');
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {

      infoWindow.open(map, marker);

    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map,
.gmaps {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" />
<!-- Google Maps API integration-->
<div class="gmaps">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you replace [KEY] in

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[KEY]...
```

with a real key which can be obtained from google developer console.
The key starts wit 'Aiza....'

Make sure the variable uluru is getting proper values i.e. floating points and not something like null or undefined.

```
var uluru = {lat:position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
```

Edited your code a bit this part was missing.

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" />
```

Now it works check it [here](http://jsbin.com/fitawumobo/edit?html,output)

[see the screenshot of autocomplete in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG9gK.png)

Comment: Everything is working fine, marker and current location is showing on google maps. But whenever I enter something i n auto complete input nothing happens and errors are displayed in console.

Comment: can you update your question with the actual,all errors logged on console. From what you have already posted there seems to be error on line 106, I dont know what exactly is on line 106, check yourself carefully.

Comment: Error is not referring any of my scripts , it showing some internal error in googleapis.com.map.places:68 like that. I am not able to properly figure it out but all the error are of the same kind as I have posted above.

Comment: its happens if there is error on your code, because those google code read values from your code

Comment: Ohk...I'll see to it. Thanks

Comment: @ChanchalRoshan i got your code fixed, check the edit of my answer.

Comment: I have an input field above with id="autocomplete". I don't know why its not working. I'll see to it. Thank you so much. Is there any error in the code that I posted?

Comment: in the code you posted the input field with id autocomplete is missing, and I hardcoded the coordinates and It works, no errors.